# Retornar um array em uma aplicação java

Tags: java, neo4j

Estou fazendo uma aplicação java que utiliza o banco de dados do neo4j. Uma das funções que chamo é para listar todos os contatos que já foram salvos no banco, porém não estou conseguindo implementar o array para agrupar esses resultados e posteriormente dar um "print". Gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo de errado e como fazer essa implementação? Desde agora agradeço a ajuda.

```
    public void listar() {
    Session session = driver.session();
    ArrayList<String> greeting = new ArrayList();

     greeting = session.writeTransaction( new TransactionWork<String>() {
        @Override
        public ArrayList<String> execute(Transaction tx) {
            StatementResult result = tx.run("" +
                "MATCH (n:contatos) "+
                "RETURN n");

            return result.single().get(0).asString();
        }
    });  
    System.out.println(greeting );
}
```